# Filter Json Listview With a EditText Android

Tags: android, json, listview, arraylist

Trying to filter my listview with a edittext, everytime i enter some text the listview becomes blank, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how i can solve this

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher (){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
    int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        String searchString = cs.toString();//wsSearch.getText().toString();
       /* if(searchString.length() != 2) {
            adapter2 = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
            return;
        }*/
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            String currentString = array.get(i).getTitulo();
            if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString))
            {
                mTemp.add(array.get(i));
            }
        }
        adapter2 = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, mTemp);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }



});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String searchString = arg0.toString();//wsSearch.getText().toString();
   /* if(searchString.length() != 2) {
        adapter2 = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
        return;
    }*/     
            mTemp.clear()
            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
            {
                String currentString = array.get(i).getTitulo();
                if (currentString.contains(searchString))
                {
                    mTemp.add(array.get(i));
                }
            }
            adapter2 = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, mTemp);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter2);

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //BAPTISMAL_SONG.this.adapter2.getFilter().filter(cs);




        }



    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when i enter a product name, it filters but it presents the same product 5x on my listview, and if i delete the text and add something new, it keeps those 5 and adds 5more from the new product

Comment: I'll edit the answer. I forgot to add clearing the list.

Comment: If you find the answer correct please mark it as correct and upvote it. It took a lot of effort to do this. :D

Comment: I upvoted, but since there are 1-2 people always downvoting my posts, i need to wait a while till my vote is confirmed , thank you, its fixed

Comment: Thank you. Happy coding.